# Xcode keeps building old/cached code on device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am developing an iOS app with react native. When I run my app on a real iOS device via Xcode, code changes are not reflected anymore. It keeps building an old code version of my app. However, as soon as I run the app in the simulator, it uses the latest code. Unfortunately, cleaning the build folder, deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and removing the old app from device did not help. Does anyone know a solution?